# modify array objects by adding property with sequential values of an array

Tags: javascript

I am trying to transform the objects in an array adding a new property `number`. The value of this property must be obtained from the array `set` using sequential values, so that the first object should have the value `1` the second the value `3` and the third the value `6` the fourth the value `1` again and so on ...

This is what I've been trying

```js
const set = [1, 3, 6];
const data = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }, { id: 4 }, { id: 5 }, { id: 6 }];
let position = 0;

const getItem = () => {
  if (position === 0) {
    position += 1;

    return set[0];
  }

  if (position <= set.length - 1) {
    return set[position];
  }

  return set[0];
};

const output = data.map((entry, index) => ({ ...entry, number: getItem() }));

console.log(output);
```

And this is the expected output

```
[
  { id: 1, number: 1 },
  { id: 2, number: 3 },
  { id: 3, number: 6 },
  { id: 4, number: 1 },
  { id: 5, number: 3 },
  { id: 6, number: 6 },
];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getItem` needs to wrap `position` back to the beginning. The easy way to do that is to use `position = (position + 1) % set.length`, like this:

```
let position = -1;
const getItem = () => {
  position = (position + 1) % set.length;
  return set[position];
};
```

Live copy:

```js
const set = [1, 3, 6];
const data = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }, { id: 4 }, { id: 5 }, { id: 6 }];
let position = -1;

const getItem = () => {
  position = (position + 1) % set.length;
  return set[position];
};

const output = data.map((entry, index) => ({ ...entry, number: getItem() }));

console.log(output);
```

...although thinking about it, there's no particular reason `position` *itself* has to wrap, so long as you use `% set.length` when retrieving from `set`:

```
let position = 0;
const getItem = () => {
  return set[position++ % set.length];
};
```

I generally wrap it (the first version) if the index is going to survive like that.

---

Or if you only need to do this within `map`, you don't need `position` or `getItem` at all, just use `index % set.length` in `map`:

```
const output = data.map((entry, index) => ({ ...entry, number: set[index % set.length] }));
```

Live copy:

```js
const set = [1, 3, 6];
const data = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }, { id: 4 }, { id: 5 }, { id: 6 }];
let position = -1;

const output = data.map((entry, index) => ({ ...entry, number: set[index % set.length] }));

console.log(output);
```

---

The `% length` thing works because it's a remainder operation: `x % y` is the remainder of integer division of `x` by `y`. `0 % 3` is `0`, `1 % 3` is `1`, `2 % 3` is `2`, and then `3 % 3` is `0` again and the cycle repeats.

Answer (score 2):

You could take a closure over the index (adjusted by the remainder with length of the array) and return new objects.

```js
const
    numbers = [1, 3, 6],
    data = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }, { id: 4 }, { id: 5 }, { id: 6 }],
    result = data.map((i => o => ({ ...o, number: numbers[i++ % numbers.length] }))(0));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```